# Is the sum of trends of two time series the trend of the sum of the time series?

Tags: time-series, trend, sum

Let's say I have two time-series, A and B. I build time-series C as C=A+B.

I estimate the trend of A, let's say I get +0.5 (Theil-Sen).
I estimate the trend of B, let's say I get -0.4 (Theil-Sen).

Can C have a trend estimate different from +0.1. Can it be negative?

Can you give a simple example when this happens (negative C trend)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is the sum of trends of two time series the trend of the sum of the time series?*

- as a general question, it depends: if the estimator is linear in the data then yes, but in general, no.

On the specific question of using Theil-Sen slope (median pairwise slope) as a trend estimate:

When using a Theil-Sen slope estimate, the trend of the sum can be quite different from the sum of the trends (the Theil-Sen slope is not linear in the observations).

Here's a small example:

Series A:

```
 -1.15 
  2.19 
  1.32 
  1.40 
  2.04
```

Series B:

```
-2.63
-0.98
-1.23
-1.68
-5.86
```

The Theil-Sen slope for the first (unit-spaced) series is 0.5, the Theil-Sen slope for the second series is -0.4 (as in your question) but the slope for the sum is negative (indeed, it's -0.5575, more negative that for the second series).

[image: plot of the two series and their sum, with the fitted Theil-Sen regression lines ("trend"); the third line slopes down more rapidly than the sum of the two original fitted trends]

Comment: Thinking about how to construct examples with desired properties can be instructive, often teaching quite different sorts of lessons than the resulting examples convey.

Comment: Thank you, this example is very interesting. I wonder that a linear estimator would be the slope in a linear regression, right?

Comment: That's an example of a linear estimator, yes. (More specifically, you can write $\hat{y}=Hy$, for a constant-matrix $H$, where for this particular problem the values in $H$ will only depend on the gaps between various observation-times). This is certainly the case for linear regression (though it's not the only such linear estimator)